# Sync user data from amazon cognito to my mysql database from laravel after user is registered

Tags: mysql, reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-cognito

I need to use AWS Cognito user authentication service with my React-Native app and also store user data through my mysql database from my laravel backend..

is there a way after user is registered in aws cognito, to send all its data to my mysql database and store it in my users table? like the email, name, cellphone

so after I can be able to use my 'mysql' database to makes queries inside my app..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I have a similar dilemma and am trying to figure out if this is a good idea to sync the data or better use Cognito API for all user related queries. Any thoughts on that? You seem to be at a similar point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Cognito Trigger for it, for example

[Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-post-confirmation.html)

[Example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-post-confirmation.html#aws-lambda-triggers-post-confirmation-example)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, just one more question.. So I can create a function in my ''Post Confirmation Lambda Trigger'' where it sends user data trough my Laravel REST API, so later it can store it in my local mysql users table?

Comment: Once you have the lambda for triggers. You have a full control with data. So yes for your question